# Как проверить загружаемый json файл на подходящую структуру?

Tags: php, массивы, json, проверка

Есть json файл с такой структурой, в виде теста, таких на сервер может загружаться множество. Как при загрузке файла проверять, чтобы он соответствовал именно такой структуре?

Распарсить в массив и проверить с помощью array_key_exists?

Приведите пожалуйста пример кода, понятия не имею как это делается.

```
[{
"question": "Столица России?",
"answers": 
    {
    "1": "Париж",
    "2": "Вашингтон",
    "3": "Питер",
    "4": "Москва"
        },
"correct_answer": "Москва"
},
{
    "question": "Какой сейчас год?",
    "answers": 
        {
        "1": "2025",
        "2": "1991",
        "3": "2017",
        "4": "2013"
        },
    "correct_answer": "2017"
},
{
    "question": "Сколько дней в январе?",
    "answers": 
        {
        "1": "31",
        "2": "29",
        "3": "30",
        "4": "28"
        },
    "correct_answer": "31"
}]
```

Ниже скрипт загрузки файлов.

```
<?php
$json = "json";
$file_dir = './tests';


if (is_dir("tests")) {
}else {
    mkdir("tests", 0700);
}





if (isset($_FILES['myfile']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['myfile']['name'])) {
    $file_name = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
    $explode = explode(".", $file_name);



    if ($explode[1] !== $json) {
        echo "<script>alert(\"Можно загружать только файлы с разрешением json.\");</script>";
    } else { //ессли имеет формат json то:


        if ($_FILES['myfile']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], "$file_dir/$file_name")) {
            echo "<script>alert(\"Файл с тестами успешно загружен\");</script>";}

         else {
            echo "<script>alert(\"Не удалось загрузить файл с тестами.\");</script>";}
        }  
}

?> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="list.php">Список тестов</a></li>
        <li><a href="admin.php">Загрузить тест</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#" method="POST">
    Тест в формате json: <input name="myfile" type="file"/>
    <br/>
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Отправить" name="otpravit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А откуда эти файлы берутся ? при создании файла надо создать по такой структуре и все.

Comment: Файлы загружаются пользователем через форму отправки методом POST. Важно сделать, чтобы если структура не соответствовала, файл не загружался. [скрин](https://gyazo.com/93b7647d183d691f24173dcb9c1dae7e)

Comment: А содержание проверять тоже надо? Например, что правильный ответ есть среди ответов? )

Comment: Вот уже какой то ответ есть, но все ровно не понятно как то? пользователь должен загружать на ваш сервер вопросы в `json` формате?

Comment: так и вирусы можно подхватить и заболеть.)))))

Comment: @splash58 Нет, достаточно проверки на 3 основных ключа. Да пользователь загружает в json формате, я вроде как сделал проверку, но ее легко обойти, в любом случае задание тестовое. В основном посте прикрепил скрипт по загрузке файлов.

Comment: Обычно для проверок такого типа используют схемы (JSON-Schema), как пример статья об них (https://habrahabr.ru/post/158927/)

Comment: Благодарю. Ознакомлюсь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$check_keys = ['question', 'answers', 'correct_answer'];    
foreach ($response as $arr) {
    foreach ($check_keys as $key) {
        if(array_key_exists($key, $arr)) {continue;}else{break;}
    }
}
```

Ну как то так, ну можешь ещё проверку на массивы добавить что $response и $arr являются массивами

Comment: Куда это впихнуть, чтобы исполнялось при проверке подгружаемого файла (то есть конкретный файл)

Comment: //Получаешь файл
$file = file_get_contents($_FILES['tmp_name']);
//Потом переводишь JSON в массив 
$response = json_decode($file, true);

А потом уже проверяешь скриптом выше

Comment: @Sindr0me Разобрался?

Comment: [Скриншот](https://i.gyazo.com/57e47b35f1059cbd16529aa776fc7842.png) Выдает по 9 раз если не соответствует и 9 раз если подгружен и столько же если не верная структура. Запутался) А так проверяет верно.

Comment: Разобрался) Спасибо!